# Identify plant?

Tags: identification, pruning, plant-care

Can anyone help me identify this plant. Someone told me In passing that it needs to be pruned back every Fall, but I’d like to read up on the specifics first.

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

It looks like some species of yucca to me. Compare http://lifescapecolorado.com/2013/06/why-yuccas-are-our-best-friend/

They don't need any pruning, but you can trim off any dead leaves and remove the old flower stalks in spring.

Comment: Yes, certainly *Yucca*. It could be *Yucca aloifolia* 'Purpurea', but flowers would be helpful for correct ID.

Comment: Trimming is personal choice, in my opinion. It won't affect how a Yucca grows. As my grandfather always said "A yucca will do what a yucca do". If it was my plant, I'd cut all the dead stuff off it, more for style points than anything else. There is something to be said for the "au naturel" look.